# Display custom button on Task in Salesforce Mobile

Tags: custom-button, mobile, leads

In a customer org we have a custom button called "Log a Visit" on tasks, which creates a new task of a custom record type and importantly pre-populates the new task from the lead(see screenshots below) via URL hacking:

Lead:
[image: Screenshot of Activity History Buttons]

Example of pre populated task:
[image: Example of pre-populated task]

We are now trying to expose this on Salesforce mobile for the client, but the custom button is not visible. When we click the "Log a Call" button from the mobile app we can select our custom record type but of course nothing is pre-populated.  Since we haven't come from our custom button the URL hacking has not occurred.

My question is: Can we expose our custom task button (Log a Visit) in Salesforce mobile? I haven't been able to find how to do so. Is there some way we can pre-populate our fields when we select our custom record type(Visit)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible to add custom buttons to Salesforce Mobile. I've seen a video demo of the next version of Chatter Mobile where they make use of the new Chatter Actions there. Until then, there isn't a way to get custom buttons in mobile unless you use the standard web interface.